# SI4T unpublish components error 'cannot parse' query

Tags: si4t

Has anyone seen the following error when unpublishing components using SI4T?

Looks like the query format has not been escaped. We have not changed the default behaviour. Unpublishing works fine in our Development environment.

Error:

> org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:
>   org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse
>   'id:*dcp:18-2251-1070t*': Encountered " ":" ": "" at line 1, column 7.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It's puzzling why this should work on your development environment and not on any other environment. Do you perhaps use different version of Solr? 

In any case: this is a confirmed defect in the current build of SI4T and will be addressed asap.